# Vaadin Util Logger Exception

Tags: java, exception, logging, vaadin

Firstly the Logger like this works in other projects without the vaadin framework fine.

I implempent the logger in a seperate class like this, but with vaadin it won´t works:

```
    Level cfgLevel = getConfigLevel();

    // create logger
    this.logger = Logger.getLogger(GZ_IOLogger.class.getName());
    this.logger.setLevel(cfgLevel);

    // create console handler for console outputs
    ConsoleHandler cHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
    cHandler.setLevel(cfgLevel);
    this.logger.addHandler(cHandler);

    // create filehandler for fileoutputs
    try {
        //logger path in web-inf
        String loggerPath = "logs/logs.txt";

        //get vaadin resource from web-inf
        File file = this.session.getResource(loggerPath);
        //!exception line!
        FileHandler handler = new FileHandler(file.getAbsolutePath());
        this.logger.addHandler(handler);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        System.err.println("Logger-Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Logger-Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I always get the following exception:

```
Logger-Exception: C:\Users\XXX\IdeaProjects\Backend\out\artifacts\Backend_war_exploded\WEB-INF\log\logs.txt.lck
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\XXX\IdeaProjects\Backend\out\artifacts\Backend_war_exploded\WEB-INF\log\logs.txt.lck
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:115)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:287)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:335)
    at java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(FileHandler.java:459)
    at java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:292)
    at io.GZ_IOLogger.initLogger(GZ_IOLogger.java:57)
...
```

I think it is maybe not possible to create there files and the logger try´s to create a locked file. Is there a solution for loggers? I tried it also to use a absolute path like C:/test but it wont work, too.

Comment: What is the exact version of Java that this code is executed under?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure all the directories exist before you create FileHandler.  The FileHandler will not create directories if they don't exist.

```
File file = this.session.getResource(loggerPath);
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
//!exception line!
FileHandler handler = new FileHandler(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: The directories and files are available.